# regular expression and reorganize web page for iPhone

Tags: iphone

I noticed that there are some apps main function is to load the web page of a website and customize the better view for iPhone.
I think it will analyse the html source codes.
But I hope to know if there is any existed frame to do this, or I need analyse the html pages by myself base on regular expression?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to rewrite an HTML to render on iPhone, instead of Regular Expression, I would suggest you to create your view with a proper tool like Apple's DashCode.

Unfortunately, it's only available for Mac OS X.